# Regex pattern to count lines in poems with randomly \n or \n\n as line breaks

Tags: r, regex, nlp, data-science, quanteda

I need to count the lines of 221 poems and tried counting the line breaks \n.

However, some lines have double line breaks \n\n to make a new verse. These I only want counted as one. The amount and position of double line breaks is random in each poem.

Minimal working example:

```
library("quanteda")

poem1 <- "This is a line\nThis is a line\n\nAnother line\n\nAnd another one\nThis is the last one"
poem2 <- "Some poetry\n\nMore poetic stuff\nAnother very poetic line\n\nThis is the last line of the poem"

poems <- quanteda::corpus(poem1, poem2)
```

The resulting line count should be 5 lines for `poem1` and 4 lines for `poem2`.

I tried `stringi::stri_count_fixed(texts(poems), pattern = "\n")`, but the regex pattern is not elaborate enough to account for the random double line break problem.

Comment: No, use `"\\R+"`, it matches any one or more line break sequences as one match.

Comment: But \n\n should only be counted as one

Comment: But you should not use `_fixed` function with regex. It should be `stringi::stri_count_regex`. Or `stringr::str_count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_count` with the `\R+` pattern to find the *number of consecutive line break sequences* in the string:

```r
> poem1 <- "This is a line\nThis is a line\n\nAnother line\n\nAnd another one\nThis is the last one"
> poem2 <- "Some poetry\n\nMore poetic stuff\nAnother very poetic line\n\nThis is the last line of the poem"
> library(stringr)
> str_count(poem1, "\\R+")
[1] 4
> str_count(poem2, "\\R+")
[1] 3
```

So the *line count* is `str_count(x, "\\R+") + 1`.

The `\R` pattern matches any line break sequence, CRLF, LF or CR. `\R+` matches a sequence of one or more such line break sequence.

**See the [R code DEMO online](https://ideone.com/m8oT93)**:

```r
poem1 <- "This is a line\nThis is a line\n\nAnother line\n\nAnd another one\nThis is the last one"
poem2 <- "Some poetry\n\nMore poetic stuff\nAnother very poetic line\n\nThis is the last line of the poem"
library(stringr)
str_count(poem1, "\\R+")
# => [1] 4
str_count(poem2, "\\R+")
# => [1] 3
## Line counts:
str_count(poem1, "\\R+") + 1
# => [1] 5
str_count(poem2, "\\R+") + 1
# => [1] 4
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the rationale behind your answer, I was happy to learn about the line break matching with \R.